# Why can't I download any plugins through Install New Software?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jetty

I am unable to download any plugins for Eclipse through Install New Software, or via Marketplace. The specific plugin I am after is Run-Jetty-Run, but after some testing, I noticed I couldn't download anything, even from the Eclipse update sources.

I'm running the latest version of Indigo, and am using Win7 64-bit. My machine is behind a router and running AVG Free. 
Things I have already tried: 
Forwarding port 4000 
Running Eclipse as Administrator 
Adding exception for Eclipse in Windows Firewall

When trying to download the sources for RJR, I get a "Provisioning exception" in the error log, but no pop-up message. The trace is huge, will post if necessary. Eventually I get to the screen where I accept the license agreement, and the download starts but hangs at a step labeled Fetching [repository URL]. After a time, I get this pop-up error:

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://run-jetty-run.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/updatesite/plugins/runjettyrun_1.3.3.201203161919.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at http://run-jetty-run.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/updatesite/plugins/runjettyrun.jetty7_1.3.3.201203161919.jar.
Read timed out

[The last three lines are repeated again, but my reputation is too low to post another link]

I know this is not the repository itself that is failing - every plugin I have tried to load has failed in an analogous way with the same sort of error message, and I can download the jars just fine through my browser.

Comment: I just tried downloading run-jetty-run and I had no problem downloading it through eclipse.  Have you tried installing any other plugin with your eclipse?

Comment: Until better idea comes along I'd also check file protection on eclipse installation, check if java version is not outdated and possibly try to reinstall eclipse.

Comment: I've tried downloading other plugins. None work.

Java is up to date, and a fresh install of Eclipse didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Not sure why this question was downvoted.  This seems perfectly fine to me.

Comment: Same thing happens to me. Stuck at 38% all the time. Proxy settings make no difference either way (manual/direct). Can't update or install any new software through market place. I used to be able to use this feature, but apparently something changed that Ican't identify. This is with Indigo as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the problem that one gets when there is some kind of firewall or if your proxies are not set up properly.  Have you gone to Preferences -> General -> Network Settings and set up your proxy configuration there?

If this doesn't work, then some projects have archived update sites that you can download. Try looking for one of them, downloading and installing from the local update site.